# How to troubleshoot CAN bus communication

Tags: can-bus

I am trying to connect ICP CON i-7565 (USB<->CAN interface) to a custom made device (supporting CAN2.0B, proved to work with PCL-841 card) Although I think I have configured BAUD and acceptance code/mask correctly I can see CAN no messages coming from the device (ICP provides a tool that should allow me to send and receive CAN messages).

I am new to CAN bus so I appreciate any help regarding how to identify the problem.

I-7565 might be wrong interface for me, I might have misconfigured it, or it is simply broken. Or I am just doing something wrong out of my ignorance. I don't think anyone can help me with my specific problem, so I am rather asking for general information on how are problems with CAN bus identified and analyzed. In TCP/IP for example, you would call ping, you'd recheck your ip and gateway settings etc. What do you do for CAN communication?

Additional info:

OS: Win7 64bit
connector: DB-9 with standard wiring (2,3,7)

Comment: What is the connection between I7565 and your Custom made device? Have you used 120 Ohm Termination resistor?

Comment: What's your operating system, where USB<->CAN is connected to?

Comment: @yegorich: My OS is Win7 64bit

Comment: @Swanand Purankar: cable with DB-9 connector. Yes, I-7565 comes with switchable 120Ohm resistor. Doesn't work regardless if resistor is enabled or disabled.

Comment: What? Not Linux? :-) What software are you using? Can you use [Busmaster](http://rbei-etas.github.io/busmaster/)? Can you read status flags, so that you could tell, if device is in a bus error state? Bus error means either wiring or bitrate is wrong.

Comment: manufacturer of the interface (ICP) ships it with driver and test utility. There is nothing appearing in received messages even when I connect it to the same bus with old terminal and let them to communicate. I downloaded Busmaster, but it doesnt support my device. I am afraid I will have to get different USB-CAN interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I tried to work with different USB<->CAN interface from different manufacturer and it worked like a charm. My old interface was either broken or incompatible for reasons unknown. While working on this problem I learned couple of things about CAN bus and so now I share what I think was the right answer to my original question: How to troubleshoot CAN bus communication?

- read manual to your USB-CAN interface
- install **driver** of your interface device and make sure it is working (check device manager, depending on the type of your device you will see new COM port added or new USB controller )
- your device should be shipped with it's own **test/analysis software** (they might call it utility or similar), run it and check if it can connect to your device
- CAN communication uses three wires that are referred to as **High**, **Low** and **Ground** and is usually connected with **DB-9** connectors where High is linked to pin n. 7, Low to pin n. 2 and Ground to pin n. 3 or 5 - make sure this is connected correctly on both your USB interface and CAN device you want to communicate with
- set properties of your connection, these are most of all: **CAN type** (2.0A or 2.0B) **BAUD rate**, **Acceptance Code** and **Acceptance Mask**
- if you've done all of this and still you can see no CAN messages arriving in your utility program, **check with a different USB-CAN interface** or find some other way to test if your device is actually emitting CAN messages and your USB interface is in fact able to receive them. (this was actually my case)